# Why exists the exchange rate between countries?

Tags: foreign-exchange

To build something of worth needs everywhere the same work and effort. Why is it cheaper for Europeans to purchase abroad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect; "To build something of worth needs everywhere the same work and effort." is completely untrue. The simplest example might be that in the UK (where I am now) it would be much harder for me to produce mangos than it would for someone in Kenya to do so. Conversely it is much harder for Kenyans to engage in high frequency trading (I'm working with clients doing this right now) than it would be for me to do so here because the *skills* are not available there. In countries where there is high unemployment labour is much less expensive than in countries where there is close to full employment.

Exchange rates are determined in part by speculation but mostly, and in aggregate, by demand and supply of these underlying factors and the relationship between the various countries' imports and exports. You will find that it is cheaper for Europeans to buy *some things* abroad but others will be cheaper for outsiders to but in Europe.